# How to get mobile device id using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How to get the mobile device id or token to send push notifications using apn_on_rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The device must send the id to your application, e.g. during the registration process.